# MVVM Main window control bind from child user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I’m very new to MVVM and getting my first POC done now. However, I have been hitting my head to get one issue resolved for 2 days. Thought of explaining to you guys may help and resolve the issue so quickly. Let me brief my issue now.
I have WPF MVVM application with a main View bound to MainViewModel. I have Textblock here to bind some content from the viewmodel while loading the screen which is working awesome.
I also have ChildUserControl bound to ChildViewModel. Now, I need to bind different content to the Textblock in the main window from user control up on some action which is taking place in user control level. How it is possible ?

here is the sample code I have
MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="mainWindowViewModel"/></Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Name="txtStatus" Text="{Binding StatusMessage, Mode=OneWay }"/>
```

ChildUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:ChildModelView x:Key="ChildModelView"/> </UserControl.Resources>

public class ChildModelView : BaseViewModel
{
// Some child level logic..
// then need to update the txtStatus text block from parent
}
```

Your helps are much appreciated..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this would be to use IoC. When you create your child view model, pass a reference of your main view model to your child viewmodel , and hold it as a private read only variable. You now access all of your main VM publics .

An alternative solution would ppossibly be to use the Mediator pattern.

Knocked up a simple App to demonstrate IoC solution.

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var window = new MainWindow() {DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() };
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _statusMessage;

    public string StatusMessage
    {
        get { return _statusMessage; }
        set { _statusMessage = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("StatusMessage"); }
    }

    public ICommand OpenChildCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.StatusMessage = "No status";
        this.OpenChildCommand = new DelegateCommand((o) => this.OpenChild());
    }

    private void OpenChild()
    {
        var window = new ChildWindow {DataContext = new ChildWindowViewModel(this)};
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

ChildWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class ChildWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly MainWindowViewModel _mainvm;

    public ChildWindowViewModel(MainWindowViewModel mainvm)
    {
        _mainvm = mainvm;
        this.UpdateStatusCommand = new DelegateCommand((o) => this.UpdateStatus());
    }

    public ICommand UpdateStatusCommand { get; private set; }

    private void UpdateStatus()
    {
        this._mainvm.StatusMessage = "New Status";
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand.cs

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Action to be performed when this command is executed
    /// </summary>
    private Action<object> executionAction;

    /// <summary>
    /// Predicate to determine if the command is valid for execution
    /// </summary>
    private Predicate<object> canExecutePredicate;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the DelegateCommand class.
    /// The command will always be valid for execution.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The delegate to call on execution</param>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the DelegateCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The delegate to call on execution</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The predicate to determine if command is valid for execution</param>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        this.executionAction = execute;
        this.canExecutePredicate = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when CanExecute is changed
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the delegate backing this DelegateCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">parameter to pass to predicate</param>
    /// <returns>True if command is valid for execution</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecutePredicate == null ? true : this.canExecutePredicate(parameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the delegate backing this DelegateCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">parameter to pass to delegate</param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown if CanExecute returns false</exception>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (!this.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The command is not valid for execution, check the CanExecute method before attempting to execute.");
        }
        this.executionAction(parameter);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Open Child Window" 
            Command="{Binding Path=OpenChildCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ChildWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.ChildWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ChildWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="UpdateStatus"
            Command="{Binding Path=UpdateStatusCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Image before clicking on update status

[image: Before]

Image after clicking on updatestatus

[image]

Comment: I did pass the main view model while initiating ChildVM and set the MainVM property some value. But it did nor reflected over the page.. no idea why.

Comment: Are you implementing INPC on the mainvm and calling propertychanged on the mainvm property?

Comment: This is wat im doing in my MainMV   public string StatusMessage
        {
            get { return statusMsg; }
            set
            {
                statusMsg = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusMessage");
            }
        }
Then while initializing the child vm im doing ChildVM(mainVM vm) { _main = vm; _main.StatusMessage = "new status"; Is it the right way?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Are you also assigning the mainvm to the DataContext of main window? In your App.xaml.cs you should be overriding OnStartup and creating your mainvm, then create your mainwindow and assign mainvm to datacontext. Ie var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }; window.Show();

Comment: I can see that you have your mainviewmodel in the resources but I don't it will work this way. I've gotta head off to work but will be back to check if you need more help in about an hour

Comment: Yes, i have the same code in mainVM too :(. No idea where im missing things. BTW, when we initiate the child VM im passing a new MainVM instance to it, not the one which has already out there.. like ChileVM cVM = new ChildVM(new MainVM()); ?? will that make any diff?

Comment: You have to pass the existing MainVm instance to the childvm! The existing mainwindow DataContext is bound to the existing MainVm, if you create a new MainVm, it is not bound to the existing MainWindow and changes will not appear in the MainWindow

Comment: Hmm.. failedprogramming, I have a question for you. MVVM is all about separation of concerns. However, in "OpenChild()" method of your "MainWindowViewModel" class, you are instantiating a hard-coded VIEW and its ViewModel. Isn't that a tight-coupling? If I wanted to replace a ChildWindow and ChildWindowViewModel with ChildWindow1 and ChildWindowViewModel1, I would have to modify MainWindowViewModel too. Is there a better way?

Comment: @SamDevx You could create a separate class that takes care of opening windows and pass this class to the MainWindowViewModel. Changes to the window opening code could then be made without affecting MainWindowViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your needs here, but it sounds like you have a TextBlock in the MainWindow that needs to be updated in response to something that occurs in and with data supplied by the ChildWindow. Assuming that's what you're trying to do then I think there are a few different ways that you could do it. In particular, you could use an attached event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx

The technical explanation is a bit lengthy, so I'll leave it to MSDN to do that, but the short explanation is simply that it's just an event that will be raised from your child window and handled by your MainWindow. The bonus here is that it will pass in your ChildWindowViewModel as the DataContext.