# Handling Navigation in MVVM WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application that follows MVVM. Now I am handling navigation of views in the following manner.
MainWindow View

```
<Border>
    <StackPanel>
    <local:Home
               Content="{Binding CurrentView,Converter={StaticResource ViewConverterHome}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <local:Page1
            Content="{Binding CurrentView,Converter={StaticResource ViewConverterPage1}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <local:Page2
        Content="{Binding CurrentView,Converter={StaticResource ViewConverterPage2}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Border>
```

Home, Page1,Page2 are 3 views. HomeVM,Page1VM,Page2VM are view models corresponding to the views. There is a class call ApplicationViewModel that contains a property CurrentView of type CViewModelBase which is the parent class for all three viewmodels. ApplicationViewModel handles the navigation in the folowing manner

```
   private void OnUserInputNextClicked(object sender, OperationInformationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            if (this.CurrentView is HomeVM)
            {
                this.CurrentView = null;
                Page1VM page1 = new Page1VM("BNM", "MATH HONS", "13");
                page1.NextCilcked += new EventHandler<OperationInformationChangedEventArgs>(OnUserInputNextClicked);
                page1.BackCilcked += new EventHandler<OperationInformationChangedEventArgs>(OnUserInputBackClicked);
                this.CurrentView = page1;
                break;
            }

            if (this.CurrentView is Page1VM)
            {
                this.CurrentView = null;
                Page2VM page2 = new Page2VM("Kolkata", "Monoj", "Itachuna");
                page2.NextCilcked += new EventHandler<OperationInformationChangedEventArgs>(OnUserInputNextClicked);
                page2.BackCilcked += new EventHandler<OperationInformationChangedEventArgs>(OnUserInputBackClicked);
                this.CurrentView = page2;
                break;
            }
            if (this.CurrentView is Page2VM)
            {
                this.CurrentView = null;
                HomeVM home = new HomeVM("Anirban", "30");
                home.NextCilcked += new EventHandler<OperationInformationChangedEventArgs>(OnUserInputNextClicked);
                this.CurrentView = home;
                break;
            }
        } while (false);
    }
```

The navigation is working perfectly; But dispose of disappeared views are not getting called.So all the views live till the end. Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Views will always exist because you added a copy of each one to your UI with the XAML, even if the `Content` contained in them may not exist

Typically I will use a `ContentControl` to display content instead of creating an instance of the control for each content type, and I'll use `DataTemplates` to tell WPF how to draw each type of content.

For example,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeVM}">
        <local:Home Content="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page1VM}">
        <local:Page1 Content="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page2VM}">
        <local:Page2 Content="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Border>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

This way, you only have one instance of your `Content` in the VisualTree, and the `DataTemplate` WPF users to draw your content changes based on it's `DataType`.

I have an [example of this kind of navigation with WPF](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) on my blog if you're interested in checking out a full code sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to change DataContext of MainWindow. It depends on your integration. When I make a MVVM application what I do is that pass MainWindow object to every view constructor. And whenever I have to move to next page (like on next button) I change the MainWindow object DataContext to new view.

Something like this.

```
public PageOneViewModel
{

    private MainWindow _mainWindow;
    public PageOneViewModel(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
         // Here I am saving MainWindow object.
         _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public OnNext()
    {
         // Here I am changing the view.
         MainWindow.DataContext = new PageTwoViewModel(_mainWindow);
    }
}
```

Comment: After all MainWindow is a view; I am not sure whether I should pass a view object to a viewModel constructor.

Comment: MainWindow is not a view. It is actually a window which hosts different views. Well it depends on your implementation. I do this and this works and no rules are broken by this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Frame?

```
<Frame Name="YourFrame" Navigated="OnNavigated"/>
```

and then you can call

> YourFrame.CanGoBack(), YourFrame.GoBack()

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418671/mvvm-main-window-control-bind-from-child-user-control/15418881#15418881) to my answer to a similar question with working source code. The technique I used is a little similar to Faisal's solution.

If you need a good downloadable sample solution that demonstrates navigation using a side menu, look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and [here(simpler example)](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/).