# Trigger Event on WPF Window from another WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have  2 WPF Windows:

- MainWindow
- Window1

After some queries executed in Window1 data are fetched and stored in List  in Window1

What I what to achieve is the following:

1. On botton clck in Window1, I want a checkbox control of MainWindow to get unckecked
2. On botton click in Window1, I want data of List to be loaded in datagrd1 in MainWindow

Considering #2, I tried to impelement a public static method in MainWindow and call it in botton click, from Window1 but the problem was that I could reference the datagrid1 inside that method. The error was: "Could not reference on non static field datagrid1".

Is there a way to Impement the above?
Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using Data binding and mvvm. Refer here for a simple app that uses these techniques to communicate between windows.

[MVVM Main window control bind from child user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418671/mvvm-main-window-control-bind-from-child-user-control/15418881#15418881)

**Edit**
Using the techniques I describe will require you to address your problem in a different way, and will not solve the problem with your existing code. But I believe that this is better than trying to use static methods and manipulate uielements

Comment: Why the down vote? Are you saying data binding and mvvm can't solve the problem?

Comment: The error occurs because the OP is using a static method. We would not use this in mvvm, we would rather use ICommands.

Comment: I upvotted since After small examination of the link a think that the answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current instance of MainWindow:

```
MainWindow main = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

I couldn't suggest a better approach since your question isn't giving much information on how the windows are interacting, but this should give you what you want.