# How to switch views within one window from button in child view in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an issue with switching views in a WPF MVVM app. 
When clicking on menu items defined in the main view, switching works fine.
When clicking on a button in a child view, switching does not work as expected.

If I set contentcontrol in child view (where the button is) as well as parent view, 
the child view gets displayed mixed with previous displayed view, a button from one view and background from the one I want to switch to. 
Without it, the debugger shows something happening, similar steps in the ViewModelBase class to what happened when choosing from the menu mentioned above but no visual changes in the window.

I have commands in a ViewmodelBase (that all viewmodels inherit from either directly or through a mainviewmodel) class that gets called from bindings such as in the XAML above.
CurrentViewModel is a property in ViewModelBase that is used to determine which view gets displayed. In the constructor of ViewModelBase i set commands for example:

```
CategoryVMCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteCategoryVMCommand());
```

(RelayCommand from the line above comes from the MVVM light framework, 
although its not necessary for the solution to use that framework)

I found many tutorials and answers for similar problems, but couldnt get any of them to work. For example I tried, without success, using IOC for a similar problem in the below link:
[MVVM Main window control bind from child user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418671/mvvm-main-window-control-bind-from-child-user-control?rq=1)

Here are some of the code involved and description of what Im doing:

Main Window:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />

    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,50">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"  Command="{Binding CategoryVMCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_New">
                <MenuItem Header="_Create" Command="{Binding MainControlVMCommand}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel></StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>


</Grid>
</Window>
```

Then I select Menu item New, the following view is displayed:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" />-->

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="144" FontSize="24"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="TITLE"/><LineBreak/><Run Language="en-gb"/></TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Open category" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" Height="63" Command="{Binding CategoryVMCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Create new category" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,218,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" Height="63"/>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="293,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Background="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="293,107,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Recently Used" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

button open category clicked, and Currentviewmodel set code executes (depending on ContenControl in MainControl view being commented out or not either 
return or assigned), then The ExecuteCategoryCommand get executed. Then the line with the expected command in ViewModelBase constructor executes, although
either no change or the mixed result i mentioned originally

```
ViewModelBase class:

namespace ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;


    public ICommand CategoryVMCommand { get; private set; }

    public ICommand MainControlVMCommand { get; private set; }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        MainControlVMCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteMainControlVMCommand());
        CategoryVMCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteCategoryVMCommand());
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    protected void ExecuteCategoryVMCommand()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = null;
        CurrentViewModel = new CategoryVM();
    }
    protected void ExecuteMainControlVMCommand()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = null;
        CurrentViewModel = new MainControlVM();
    }
}
}
```

So my question is how can I click the button in the child view, send command from ViewModelBase, set CurrentViewModel, and successfully switch views within one window without any visual remains of the previously displayed view?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just edited my post with more details and code.

Comment: A simpler approach would be to register ViewModels (CategoryVM etc) with IOC (SimpleIoc in MVVM light) in ViewModelBase then commands specific to VM can be registered in VM (ie CategoryVM) rather than in ViewModelBase. Regards navigation have a look into dependency injection on MVVM light Laurent Bugnion has a few good tutorials.

Comment: Did you get some solution or still facing same issues?